# Professional/ Better way of header/body/footer layout

Tags: javascript, html, css

So this is the fist way i have see this with a wrapper.

```
 <body>
   <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="header">  
       <h1>My page</h1>
       <!-- Header content -->
   </div>

   <div id="main">
   <!-- Page content -->
   </div> 

  <div id="footer">
  <!-- Footer content -->
 </div>
 </div>
</body
```

This is the second way with out a wrapper , i just wanted to know the better most used way even if it's different than these two that will not cause problems afterwards in my page.

```
 <body>
     <div id="header">  
       <h1>My page</h1>
       <!-- Header content -->
   </div>

   <div id="main">
   <!-- Page content -->
   </div> 

  <div id="footer">
  <!-- Footer content -->
 </div>   
</body
```

Comment: This is completely subjective/dependent on what exactly you're trying to do. If you need the wrapper, put it in, if you don't, take it out.

Comment: both ways are bad, use the appropriate semantic elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the latest HTML5, the goal is to have [semantic markup](http://html5doctor.com/lets-talk-about-semantics/) without additional/unnecessary elements that are only used for styling.

Using a "wrapper" `div` was common practice for a long time, but if it doesn't actually contain semantic content & is only used for something like a bg image or centering content, you should use CSS to achieve those layout effects instead.

HTML5 also has [new elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element) including `<header>` `<article>` and `<footer>` specifically to aid in making the semantic structure more clear. That would be the most modern "correct" approach, but of course that also depends somewhat on your specific site & visitors.

In some cases, depending on what old browsers your visitors may use, you still might need to use "HTML5 shim/shiv" or script like `modernizr.js` to ensure  older browsers can recognize & understand those new elements. This is becoming less necessary as now nearly all browsers in use will handle the new HTML5 elements properly, but you still might take a look at it.

Comment: thanks for your time you really helped me.